# -SOLVED- I was Making a new genesis block and i got this error

Tags: litecoin

following [this](https://github.com/Peershares/Peershares/wiki/Genesis-Block-%28Starting-a-New-Blockchain-Instance%29) guide i solved my problem
my psztime was so long so i had to make it short and all were solved :) it successfully compiled and run pretty well

I was making a new genesis block, all was successfully but when I launch the new

```
 main.cpp:2747: bool LoadBlockIndex(bool): Assertion
 `block.CheckBlock()' failed. Aborted
```

I don't know what that means. I replaced the block.GetHash(), the hashMerkleRoot and also the block.nNonce in to the corresponding files but it won't work.

Anyone knows what is wrong?

This is my dump

```
CBlock(hash=000008d24b2b4473cf5ceb4c858b31dbd4d812c20cb5a6d60002e55a88cf6bf3, ver=1, hashPrevBlock=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, hashMerkleRoot=00a51fca8509df84304bc58ee4da87b67552829d83c19faaea3358dc9a582cc6, nTime=1508815578, nBits=1e0fffff, nNonce=80207, vtx=1, vchBlockSig=)
  Coinbase(hash=00a51fca85, nTime=1508815578, ver=1, vin.size=1, vout.size=1, nLockTime=0)
    CTxIn(COutPoint(0000000000, 4294967295), coinbase 00012a4c8a4f6e65206772657920656c657068616e742062616c616e63696e6720537465702062792073746570206f6e2061207069656365206f6620737472696e672048652074686f75676874206974207761732073756368206120776f6e64657266756c207374756e7420546861742068652063616c6c656420666f7220616e6f7468657220656c657068616e74)
    CTxOut(empty)
  vMerkleTree: 00a51fca85 
block.GetHash() == 000008d24b2b4473cf5ceb4c858b31dbd4d812c20cb5a6d60002e55a88cf6bf3
block.hashMerkleRoot == 00a51fca8509df84304bc58ee4da87b67552829d83c19faaea3358dc9a582cc6
block.nTime = 1508815578 
block.nNonce = 80207
```

What to do?

Comment: what is the exact code at line 2747.  that is where your error is.  If i remember correctly you need to assert the correct hash.  You are following a guide to create your own genesis block? can u post it so I can see what you have done already

Comment: i didn't followed a guide i dont know where to find one i was searching and searching and inothing found maybe i dont know how to use google :P
this is the line content 

assert(block.CheckBlock());

this is my main.cpp file 
http://pasted.co/824fad42
and this is my main.h file 
http://pasted.co/a49efcaf

Comment: http://pasted.co/824fad42 does not display code :( im afraid.... have a look at the peershares wiki on how to generate new genesis block and new network, https://github.com/Peershares/Peershares/wiki/Genesis-Block-%28Starting-a-New-Blockchain-Instance%29

Comment: omg! weird i uploaded it again to pasted.co and checked but didnt show code so i uploaded the file to my host and it's on 
http://cyber-xtreme.net/main.cpp
i will take a look on that wiki thanks bro

Comment: @Fuzzybear thanks for your help my pszTimestamp was so long so i had to make it more small and now it's working the daemon now i just need to compile wallet and it's done! thanks for your help i followed that guide and works!

Comment: @Rodrigo - Instead of adding "solved" to title and writing it to comments, add your own answer as a regular answer and accept it, please

Comment: @Rodrigo No you did not.

Comment: @PieterWuille 
ohhhhh sorry i didn't saw the answer my question button

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Following [this](https://github.com/Peershares/Peershares/wiki/Genesis-Block-%28Starting-a-New-Blockchain-Instance%29) guide solved my problem my psztime was so long, so I had to make it short and they all were solved :) It successfully compiled and ran pretty well.